# Making a label selectable in wxHaskell

Tags: user-interface, haskell, copy-paste, wxhaskell

I am writing a utility application in wxHaskell, and the users of this application will frequently need to copy-and-paste from the output of the application into other programs on their computer.  The output of the program is fundamentally textual, and is displayed in a `staticText` widget.

How can I make it possible for the user to select the text in this `staticText` control?  I can't find any attributes for making non-editable text selectable in the wxHaskell documentation.